# Finding greatest or least value of f(x)

Tags: functions

I have the question "Find the greatest or least value of f(X) where f(X) is   3 -2X - X^2"

So I made the quadratic into f(X) = -X^2 +2X - 3 and the final answer that I get is -4, however the solutions say that the answer should be positive 4 so have I made a mistake when rearranging the quadratic equation ?

Comment: You think $-4$ is a max or a min?

Comment: If you show your working, it'll be much easier for us (and you!) to see where you went wrong.

Comment: starting with $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$ we see that $f(x)=-(x+1)^2+4$...does that clarify things?

Comment: A is < 0 so greater ? Is that correct ?

Comment: Not sure what $A$ means.  If you mean the coefficient of $x^2$, so $A=-1$, then...yes, we expect a global maximum.  But $f(0)=3$ so it should be clear to you that $-4$ can't be the greatest value.

Comment: I get confused when rearranging 3 -2X - X^2 to make it a quadratic I'm not sure if it is X^2 - 2X - 3 or if it should be -X^2 - 2X + 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you rewrote $f(x) =3 -2x -x^2 $ as $f(x) = -x^2 + 2x - 3$, but that's not right.  The correct rearrangement is $f(x) = -x^{2} - 2x + 3$. :)

Comment: Ah Thank you I understand (:

Comment: But if I do that I get the answer -1 for X and when I put that into the equation I get the answer as 6 ?

Comment: @Dan Your $x$ is right.  Plugging $x= -1$ into $f(x)$ gives: $f(-1) = -(-1)^2 - 2(-1) + 3 = -1 + 2 + 3 = -1 + 5 = 4$. :)

Comment: Thanks ! (: I understand where I went wrong

Comment: @Dan Excellent! :)